# LLVM AST for loop representation

Tags: for-loop, compiler-construction, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

When analyzing structure of an Abstract Syntax Tree node for for-loop in LLVM, found out there are four params of this statement. Init, cond and incr are quite self explanatory. But what is the fourth one, which is defined as <<<"NULL">>?

```
  OMPUnrollDirective
   `-OMPCanonicalLoop
    |-ForStmt
    | |-[... (init)]
    | |-<<<"NULL">>>
    | |-[... (cond)]
    | |-[... (incr)]
    | `-CallExpr 'void'
    | `-[...]
    |-CapturedStmt
    | `-[... (distance)]
    |-CapturedStmt
    | `-[... (loop value)]
    `-DeclRefExpr 'int' lvalue Var 'i' 'int'
```

Checked official documentation and a few papers on the subject, but couldn't find an answer.